# Loading Twitter XML in Flash CS5.5 Actionscript 3 for Android /iOS

Tags: android, xml, flash, actionscript

This is probably a stupid question but I have spent the last 5 days searching the net and trying different ways to load a twitter feed into my air application for android (I would like to port it over to iOS but it needs building first)

The best results I had was loading the twitter XML feed

```
var xmlData:XML = new XML();
var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/weliebeneath.xml");
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);
loader_ul.addEventListener("complete", fileLoaded);
function fileLoaded(e:Event):void
{
   xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);

   txt.text = xmlData.text; 
}
```

But it will not load into my dynamic text box. Any ideas?

Comment: as far i know there is no CrossDomain on twitter.com Domain. You need to use a proxy in some server language like php

Comment: is `fileLoaded()` getting called? what does the XML contain?

Comment: doesn't twitter provide a jsonp feed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to comment what you did wrong in your code .. but all i can point you to is to dig some resources about XML in action script cuz this is a wide useful topic

here is what the code should look like

```
var xmlData:XML;
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader_ul.load(new URLRequest("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/weliebeneath.xml"));
loader_ul.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);
function fileLoaded(e:Event):void {
xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
txt.text=xmlData;
}
```